# Microsoft Open XML SDL 2.0 append document to template document asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, openxml-sdk

My asp.net c# web-application is creating word documents by filling an existing template word document with data. Now I need to add a further existing documents to that document as next page.

For example: My template has two pages. The document I need to append has one page. As result I want to get one word document with 3 pages.

How do I append documents to an existing word document in asp.net/c# with the Microsoft Open XML SDK 2.0?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this code to merge two documents

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
namespace altChunk
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {          
            string fileName1 = @"c:\Users\Public\Documents\Destination.docx";
            string fileName2 = @"c:\Users\Public\Documents\Source.docx";
            string testFile = @"c:\Users\Public\Documents\Test.docx";
            File.Delete(fileName1);
            File.Copy(testFile, fileName1);
            using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc =
                WordprocessingDocument.Open(fileName1, true))
            {
                string altChunkId = "AltChunkId1";
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = myDoc.MainDocumentPart;
                AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = 
                    mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
                    AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);
                using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(fileName2, FileMode.Open))
                    chunk.FeedData(fileStream);
                AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
                altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
                mainPart.Document
                    .Body
                    .InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body
                    .Elements<Paragraph>().Last());
                mainPart.Document.Save();
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

This works flawlessly and the same code is also available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.altchunk.aspx).

There is another approach that uses [Open XML PowerTools](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2011/01/24/open-xml-sdk-merging-documents.aspx)