# Asp.net MVC merging document

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, openxml

I am using kendo ui in my asp.net mvc my requirement was to print the document at client's machine which is not possible due to restrictions so what i did is i merged all the data in one document and then allow the client to download the file and print it. Everything is working fine but there is a performance issue . For example i have thousand records i am using OpenXML to replace bookmarks from the database values. I am reading one record at a time and merging the document . Right now i am testing for 1000 records but when the size of document increases the process gets slowers and when i open another page at the same time then it takes time i am using merge document method of OpenXML. I am confused what should i do

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to merge to two documents, look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017317/microsoft-open-xml-sdl-2-0-append-document-to-template-document-asp-net-c-sharp/21107225#21107225).

Its a simple merging code that does not need you copy each and every element one by one.
Hope this helps.