# Append word document to an existing document using OpenXML and C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I want to append the content of an existing `.docx` document (including all formatting/styles) to another existing document.

I found the following link but its more for duplication rather than addition: [Duplicating Word document using OpenXml and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142830/duplicating-word-document-using-openxml-and-c-sharp/)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've answered this question earlier, please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21017317/microsoft-open-xml-sdl-2-0-append-document-to-template-document-asp-net-c-sharp/21107225#21107225).

Hope this helps.